# Filtering SQL rows based on values from other rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Using a SQL Server 2016 SP1 database I have this data in table name AgentsTable:

> SELECT * FROM AgentsTable;

```
user_id         first_name  last_name   agent_id   agent_status  agent_code
2003015038088   John        Brown       22307      Retired       12345
2003015038088   John        Brown       22307      Death         12399
4432442556456   Mary        Jane        24667      Active        32133
7746234737464   Harry       Smith       29981      Retired       42354
3455555657677   Mark        Aguy        29654      Active        34655
5436546674465   Sally       Sam         22584      Retired       45464
```

The second row shows that 'John Brown' is dead (agent_status = 'Death'), so I would like to exclude all rows for that agent_id who is dead. (Note that John Brown has two different agent_codes, so there's one row for each agent_code. That's how the source data is...)

This query:

> SELECT * FROM AgentsTable WHERE agent_status = 'Retired';

Will return this:

```
user_id          first_name   last_name    agent_id   agent_status  agent_code
2003015038088    John         Brown        22307      Retired       12345
7746234737464    Harry        Smith        29981      Retired       42354
5436546674465    Sally        Sam          22584      Retired       45464
```

The result I want, where John Brown (22307) is excluded, is:

```
user_id          first_name   last_name    agent_id   agent_status  agent_code
7746234737464    Harry        Smith        29981      Retired       42354
5436546674465    Sally        Sam          22584      Retired       45464
```

How can I achieve that? In other words, how can I exclude one row based on a value in another related row?

Comment: You went from "Death" to "Retired" with no explanation. A little strange that the same agent also has 2 different values for agent_code - but perhaps the column name is poorly chosen. And since you mention the code column - why do you? How does the agent code impact the results? And what happened to Mark and Mary? They have no relationship to 22307. Are you simply searching for all retired agents who also have no associated "Death" rows?

Comment: Where there's a Death and a Retired record it probably means that the agent died after he retired from work (went on pension).

The "business rule" says that more than one different values for agent_code is not allowed, but in practice it does happen. I have no control over the folk who create the agent codes...

Mark and Mary are "Active", so they are not "Reired" or "Death" (dead). They have no relationship to 22307.

Yes, I want a list of all the Retired agents who are still alive (not = "Death").

Answer (score 0):

You can use CTE and get agents who are not deceased as given below:

```
;WITH CTE_deceasedagents AS
(
SELECT agent_id
FROM AgentsTable
WHERE agent_status = 'Death'
)
SELECT *
FROM AgentsTable as a
WHERE NOT EXISTS
(
SELECT agent_id
FROM CTE_deceasedagents as c
WHERE c.agent_id = a.agent_id
);
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM AgentsTable t1 WHERE agent_status = 'Retired' where NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM AgentsTable t2 WHERE t2.agent_status = 'Death' and t2.agent_code = t1. agent_code );

Answer (score 0):

I would just use `not exists` with a correlated subquery to ensure that no other record exists with the same `user_id` and a `'Death'` status:

```
select a.*
from agentsTable a
where not exists (
    select 1
    from agentsTable a1
    where a1.user_id = a.user_id and a1.agent_status = 'Death'
)
```